# JQuery change background and keep it

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css

My jquery code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.French').click(function(){ changeBackground(); 
    });
});

function changeBackground(){
    $("#title").css('backgroundPosition', '0px -120px' );
}
```

works beautifully only one problem : after the click the background returns to the initial state. How can I keep new background after the click?

Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: is there any other scripts interacting with this element?

Comment: no originally. it's the only script for this element, but there are other scripts for the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All working for me only thing that you can change is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.French').click(changeBackground);
});

function changeBackground(){
    $("#title").css('backgroundPosition', '0px -120px' );
}
```

here is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TY3Fn/1/) using jQuery 1.5

Comment: Once I knew the problem wasn't with the script I looked further. Finally,the problem was that that class '.French' was assigned to the link that was processed with Django. Once I used another class to click on everything worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `backgroundPosition` to `background-position`.
Also make sure you have use the latest version of JQuery (1.5).

Comment: backgroundPosition is valid. According to the `.css()` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1) "[...] jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css('background-color') and .css('backgroundColor')."

Answer (score 0):

Is the page doing a full page postback at any time?  (Reloading from the server?)

If so, I believe you'll have to keep track of the state with code.